# How to add custom menu for admin in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I am newbie to Shopify. I want to create a custom menu for admin.

Example : I want to create  Vendors (Menu Name) for admin under Apps in Shopify.

Any option is there to create own custom menu for admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the Shopify admin in any way or form.

The dashboard is a closed platform ( not like WordPress ) where you can't modify/add/remove items or links.